Should I reprocess my Grape Jam
I am worried about my jam being safe. I did not sterilize my jars before canning (I did wash and rinse). Can I reprocess the jam and sterilize the jars. It has been 3 days since I made the jam.

How long did you process the jars, and by what means?

No, don't reprocess. It won't make it any safer.
For canning, food safety requires you to follow an exact procedure, without any deviations. Only when you have a tested method and follow it to the letter, the result can be declared "safe".
Reprocessing of problematic jars is compatible with food safety, but it has to be done soon after the initial processing. Three days of room-temperature storage will make any food unsafe, unless it's shelf stable (i.e. safely canned). And this is when the cat bites its own tail: if your jars are already safe, there is no need to reprocess them. If they are already unsafe, and stayed out for more than a few hours, reprocessing will not make them safe.
On a side note, it's not clear whether your jelly is safe or not. The only way for it to be safe is to follow a known safe procedure, which has been tested and found workable for home canning. And you would have to follow that procedure with zero deviations, anything else automatically makes it unsafe. Sterilizing the jars is not required for safe canning, so that one wouldn't make your jelly unsafe per se. For anything else, please use a proper, modern canning guide to know whether you're meeting safety requirements.
